# Is it possible to reverse a PDA?

Tags: pda

I wanna know if we can reverse a PDA ? I have a PDA created with a timestamp, and I lost this timestamp... Can I get back this timestamp from reverse the PDA ? I know approximately the day, the hour, I miss minute/seconds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think it is possible to reverse a PDA because a PDA is derived using custom seeds similar to how a non-PDA publickey is derived using a seed phrase or privatekey. Hence the scenarios are similar which means it was not designed to allow for a publickey to be reverse engineered. You can try brute force if you already have the day and hour. But I would advise saving the timestamp in the PDA Account next time, that way the account can be deserialized and the timestamp can easily be retrived

Comment: I will do a bruteforce yes.. Recreate a PDA on each/seconde + milliseconds. I always save the timestamp.  
But due to an error on my part I crushed it

Comment: I confirm that the bruteforce worked, it ran for 27 consecutive hours because I generate timestamps with milliseconds so I have to derive a PDA for each millisecond, but it finally found the right PDA